# How can I detect the minimum and maximum values every 50 rows

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to detect peak values in MATLAB. I'm trying to use the `findpeaks` function. The problem is that my data consists of 4200 rows and I just want to detect the minimum and maximum point in every 50 rows.
After I'll use this code for real time accelerometer data.

This is my code:

```
[peaks,peaklocations] = findpeaks( filteredX, 'minpeakdistance', 50 );
plot( x, filteredX, x( peaklocations ), peaks, 'or' )
```

Comment: Please ask an explicit question here, such as "How can I detect the minimum and maximum values every 50 rows".

Answer (score 1):

So you want to first reshape your vector into 50 sample rows and then compute the peaks for each row.

```
A = randn(4200,1);
B = reshape (A,[50,size(A,1)/50]); %//which gives B the structure of 50*84 Matrix
pks=zeros(50,size(A,1)/50); %//pre-define and set to zero/NaN for stability
pklocations = zeros(50,size(A,1)/50); %//pre-define and set to zero/NaN for stability
for i = 1: size(A,1)/50
[pks(1:size(findpeaks(B(:,i)),1),i),pklocations(1:size(findpeaks(B(:,i)),1),i)] = findpeaks(B(:,i)); %//this gives you your peak, you can alter the parameters of the findpeaks function.
end
```

This generates 2 matrices, pklocations and pks for each of your segments. The downside ofc is that since you do not know how many peaks you will get for each segment and your matrix must have the same length of each column, so I padded it with zero, you can pad it with NaN if you want.

EDIT, since the OP is looking for only 1 maximum and 1 minimum for each 50 samples, this can easily be satisfied by the min/max function in MATLAB.

```
 A = randn(4200,1);
 B = reshape (A,[50,size(A,1)/50]); %//which gives B the structure of 50*84 Matrix
 [pks,pklocations] = max(B);
 [trghs,trghlocations] = min(B);
```

I guess alternatively, you could do a max(pks), but it is simply making it complicated.

Comment: Isn't `peaks` a build-in function?

Comment: Can you edit your code, peak locations and peak values for 84x1 format.  Its gonna be useful for me that way.

Comment: @Ahmet Kaymak when you say 84x1, do you mean you are only looking for 1 peak in each 50 sample frame?

Comment: Yeah! I looking just one peak and valley(minimum) points and their locaion in 4200 in every 50 sample. So I have to get 84 peak value with its locations and 84 valley value with its locations. Appreciate your efforts! @GameOfThrows

Comment: I can do it with my algorithm but its takes long time for  tasking so its not useful for real time system. So I have to deal with matlab's original functions. @GameOfThrows

Comment: @AhmetKaymak I have edited to code to output the max and min of each 50 samples, which happens to be the same and the maximum of all peaks, and the minimum of all troughs.

Comment: @AhmetKaymak glad to help! Plz remember to accept answer if you think it is fine :)

Comment: I've tried but I think my reputation point or something dont let me! Cause I ve opened my account today sooo I'll soon :) @GameOfThrows

Comment: @AhmetKaymak don't worry about it then :) Have a nice day!

Comment: You should always be able to accept answers, just click the check mark under the votes on the answer.